# Unresolved dependencies path org.vegas-viz:vegas_2.12:0.3.11

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, vegas-viz

I have tried to simply include Vegas dependency version 0.3.11 to my sbt.build and the dependency seems unresolved

I am using sbt version 0.1 and scala version 2.12. Intellij 2019

I cannot figure out why, are there any other dependencies needed here?

This is the error I get:

```
module not found: org.vegas-viz#vegas_2.12;0.3.11
[warn] ==== local: tried
C:\Users\squeo\.ivy2\local\org.vegasviz\vegas_2.12\0.3.11\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/vegas- 
viz/vegas_2.12/0.3.11/vegas_2.12-0.3.11.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\squeo\.sbt\preloaded\org.vegas- 
viz\vegas_2.12\0.3.11\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/squeo/.sbt/preloaded/org/vegas- 
viz/vegas_2.12/0.3.11/vegas_2.12-0.3.11.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.vegas-viz#vegas_2.12;0.3.11: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.vegas-viz:vegas_2.12:0.3.11 
[warn]            +- networkoptimizer:networkoptimizer_2.12:0.1
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: 
org.vegas-viz#vegas_2.12;0.3.11: not found
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that you're using a dependency available only for scala 2.11.

There's no Vegas dependency for scala 2.12. As you can see below

[image: mvn]